# Django: Get text value of the hyperlink when hyperlink is clicked

Tags: python, django, hyperlink, django-templates, django-views

I have a hyperlink like below and I want to get "VALUE I NEEDED" when this hyperlink is clicked

```
<a href='http://www.example.com'>VALUE I NEEDED</a>
```

In Django what I can do is the following

```
<a name = {{ value }} href='http://www.example.com'>{{  value }}</a>
```

Then in **views.py** i can do the following

```
def index(request):
    text = request.GET.get("name")
    *** SOME CODE HERE ***
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

But this is not working. Anyone please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to append the name as a querystring to the `href`:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com?name={{ value }}">{{  value }}</a>
```

Then it will appear in `request.GET`. The `name` attribute that you tried works for `input` tags and a form submission, but still a little different:

```
<input name="name" value={{ value }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string or data you want to extract in your url as slugs and from urls.py extract the value you added. It's easy to do.

For example:

urls.py

```
path('my-link/<str:value>/', views.my_link, name='my_link'),
```

your link

```
<a href="my-link/{{ value }}/">{{ value }}</a>
```

view.py

```
    def my_link(request, value):
        context = { 'value_from_link': value }
        return render(request, 'my-new-link.html', context)
```

here you get the value from the slug of the URL using urls.py(str:value) and pass it as a variable to views and then you can use it as you wish.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28835060)

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope that will help.